# Opencart Seo url double content (seo optimisation)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, opencart, canonical-link

I have setup my site correctly and its looking good with seo url, but the problem i am facing is that since i had my site indexed before now i am able to access my site both with the canonical url  and with the previous for example:

a simple product can be accessed from this url

=>https://www.dyqantaxi.com/Kufje-Maxell-Tribal-Bass-Yellow-ALB0087

as well s from this url

=> https://www.dyqantaxi.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=177

Thus leading to dublicate contente, from my point of view there is no way to force them with .htaccess, since opencart is handling seo url with php. But i am open to any suggestions. Be it changes to php, .htaccess, both and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll be able to use this url - https://www.dyqantaxi.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=177 because you know this url. No frontend users can click on a url like this if you haven't hardcoded the urls in that way.

Therefore the easiest solution is to make sure that you're using urls in opencart way, like:

`$this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product_id);`

I understood that you talking about canonical urls.
Please check: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en. In this way you use canonical tags for better ranking of your website. Opencart does this by default. If you check the page source of your page, you can see:

`<link href="https://www.dyqantaxi.com/Kufje-Maxell-Tribal-Bass-Yellow-ALB0087" rel="canonical" />`

That's it. No need to worry about SEO!

Have nice day :) !!

Comment: my setup is ok, i checked thoroughly, the only problem is that since my website was indexed beforehand, and i activated this option only recently search engines got both links, if possible i wanted it to be forced in a canonical url, there are no non-canonical url in my website, and i know eventually search engines will get updated to the right url only but i wanted a quicker result and that would be only to force a 301 redirect from non-canonical url to the canonical one.

Comment: Thanks, now i am at ease :), really thank you did not notice this at any point of my research.